# Python - How to add a random number to list?

Tags: list, python-3.x, random

Hello awesome coding folks!

Does anyone have a good idea to add a random number to a list? I am trying to get a list to log the random numbers that are generated inside a loop. Here is an example of the code inside the loop:

```
stuff = {'name': 'Jack', 'age': 30, 'height': '6 foot 9 inches'}

tester = [0]

print(tester)

tester.append[random.randint(1, len(stuff))]

print(tester)
```

Apparently the output of random.randint is not subscriptable, but I'm not sure how else to write this.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: My guess: You want to generate 4 random numbers and add it to the tester list?

Answer (score 3):

```
tester.append[random.randint(1, len(stuff))]
#      wrong ^                       wrong ^

# should be
tester.append(random.randint(1, len(stuff)))
```

Methods, such as `append`, are called with parentheses rather than brackets.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, Try this

```
from random import randint # import randint from random
listone = [] # Creating a list called listone
for i in xrange(1,10): # creating a loop so numbers can add one by one upto 10 times
   ic = randint(1,10) # generating random numbers from 1 to 10
   listone.append(ic) # append that numbers to listone
   pass
print(listone) # printing list
# for fun you can sort this out ;)
print(sorted(listone))
```

Answer (score 0):

do this modifications in your code

```
import random
stuff = {'name': 'Jack', 'age': 30, 'height': '6 foot 9 inches'}

tester = [0]

print(tester)

tester.append(random.randint(1, len(stuff)))

print(tester)
```